# React Router 4 Link To not updating url bar

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Following the examples provided here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/examples/url-params.

I constructed my own route for my website like so:

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Route path='/' exact component={Layout} />
    <PublicRoute authed={this.state.authed} exact path='/login' component={Login} />
    <PublicRoute authed={this.state.authed} exact path='/register' component={Register} />
    <PrivateRoute authed={this.state.authed} path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path='/cachaca/:bottle' component={Layout} />

    <Route render={() => <h3>No Match</h3>} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

That is pretty similar to the example given except for the fact that the navigation (or link to) is somewhere else in the page.

The route itself is working perfectly. I can get match information, i can sucessfully check whether a user is logged in or not and so forth.

My only problem is that the URL bar isn't changing to reflect the navigation changes, so if I am sitting at localhost:3000/cachaca/1234 and click to go home, the home page will load but the URL bar will still show 'localhost:3000/cachaca/1234'.

I've seen similar posts to mine from react router 2/3 that seem to indicate that the history prop is what's causing this issue - but I don't believe that to be the case in Router 4.

In addition to that, the example in the react training website works and mine (which seems to be following the same steps) does not.

Am I missing something here? Why am I not getting the same results as in the training website.

Here is the navigation link I am using:

```
<Link to={"/"}>Home</Link>
```

Appreciate any help,
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, this is silly - but I wasted my entire day in this so will post this in the hope of saving someone else some time:

Turns out it wasn't working because I was doing my testing on the webpack-dev-server/ folder and react-router 4 seems to have a problem with that.

As soon as I went from http://localhost:3000/webpack-dev-server/cachaca/asdf to http://localhost:3000/cachaca/asdf the website started behaving as it should - both in content and its location in the URL bar.

Happy coding to all!